# Troubles installing Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am attempting to install Visual Studio 2015 Community but during the installation there is a prompt on the install wizard saying either saying:

'Microsoft build tools x86' (I would assume it's trying to build something and it will not let  me)

OR

'Creating a system restore point' (View screenshot): 
https://i.gyazo.com/2da949c61d65bcf1b5c2b66dc3bfdf29.png

I am running Windows 10 and I do not know what to do! Even if I cancel the installation it won't let me and I have to force close it using the task manager. Furthermore it has taken up nearly 5GB on my HDD and I can't even uninstall it as it is showing the same message ('Creating a system restore point')!

Any suggestions on how to go about uninstalling it and installing Visual Studio the correct way? I desperately need it for my coursework.

Thanks,
James.

Comment: What's the problem? Did you just _wait_?

Comment: Yes. I waited at least an hour. It shouldn't take that long

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio is a very large program and takes a long time to install. You need to have patience. Closing the installation with the task manager is a very bad idea. The install messes with your system files and force stopping it when it is messing with a system file results in corrupt system files.

I would restore your PC to a point before the forced stop install. Then I would start the installer and wait at least 6 hours for the installer to do something. If this does not work I suspect your computer is not suitable to run Visual Studio.

Comment: Exactly what you have explained has happened to me... A lot of my files on my computer that aren't even related to VS have corrupted... I think system restore will be the best option... Thank you for your answer. I will wait a lot longer than an hour next time!

Comment: Used a system restore and now I am installing it again. I have got this message again in the install wizard and it has been there for a an hour or so now... I will keep waiting but I wouldn't have thought this would happen, I have a very powerful laptop!

Comment: @JamesBarrett Were you getting any corruption errors before you started the install?

Comment: None at all. I still have the wizard open and its been about 3 hours now and still the sam message: https://i.gyazo.com/0ec1c4ebadb183a59a77af4785cb1819.png

Comment: Did you have Microsoft Build Tools before this install? If you get impatient, I would uninstall these first before trying again. Also, another idea would be to try Visual Studio 2015 Professional. Found Here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/vs-2015-product-editions.aspx  It says $1,000 but I am able to use for free.

Comment: It got past the Microsoft build tools stage but it then got stuck on the stage afterwards (I waited a couple of hours on that part too). I really don't know what to do :( Perhaps an older version, my unviersity is using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012, could you suggest a good website to download from which won't mess up my machine? haha

Comment: @JamesBarrett If it is taking >3 hours to get past the Microsoft Build Tools stage I suggest upgrading your computer, not downgrading the software. If you are a student, Visual Studio 2012 is available through Dreamspark

Answer (score 0):

Have you waited long enough? Visual Studio is heavy software and creating system restore point may take a while. if you want to remove it you can follow this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2015/07/17/removing-visual-studio-components-left-behind-after-an-uninstall.aspx, even if it is for VS 2013 it should work similar. If it doesn't you can use System Restore to restore to a point before you tried to install. Then use CCleaner to clear temp files and try reinstalling. Also a little recommendation, remove .NET Framework from you PC and wait for VS to install it, it might get corrupted.

Comment: How long should I be waiting? I left it on there for at least an hour once and nothing seems to be working.

Comment: It depends on your hardware, but wait at least four hours before cancelling

Comment: I am resinstalling it now and I have the same message: https://i.gyazo.com/a376c4cbc6f5846e5bf2bae63d1e436c.png I have a very powerful laptop too! I am not sure what to do. I will keep waiting anyway.

Comment: If this cannot be passed, maybe you should try installing this component first, so installer can pass it. Here is the link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159 , if this still doesn't help try getting a new Visual Studio Installer